# How to implement query searching in a specific cluster after document clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, cluster-analysis

I have two clusters as a class which has

```
Cluster : class

DocumentList : List<Document>
centroidVector : Map<String,Double>
```

Now the problem is that when the query is searched it is parsed as a file and then made into a document object , added to documentIndex and its index is constructed along with other documents . I did that because it had to go through the same procedure i.e tokenizing ,stemming etc. But now i want to implement query search in a specific cluster with which the query vector is most similar with , i.e dot product ~ 0.5 -1 . So i would have to take a dot product between the query vector and the cluster vector to do that. But i dont know how to implement it because the index is created in memory and is not stored in the database. Still in the process of doing that .

Thank you

Comment: So what exactly is your question?!? Please rethink your questions, what do you expect as answer? So far, you didn't get much answers, right? That is because your questions are vague and "what should I do", not "how do I fix this problem". This isn't *working* for an internet site like this!

Comment: Should i save the cluster vectors somewhere so that when i load a query, i could take the dot product and load only those documents for indexing that are present in the cluster? can it be done without saving? Because the point is the clusters are built along with the query document when it has been parsed.

Comment: Depends on 100 factors that you did not give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clustering is not meant for *searching* (i.e. indexing etc.). It is an analysis step meant to *find* possible unknown structure within your data set, not to retrieve information faster.
You can exploit the structure *sometimes* for faster search, but then you need an index that can make use of this.

Just do an index right away if you want to do similarity search! Then try to improve the index by doing some clustering before.

Comment: what do you mean by possible unknown structure in data set ?

Comment: That it is an *explorative* method. You want to *explore* your data with it.

Comment: Oh right. I was under the expression that there would be a way out to make IR faster. Thanks. And sorry for the vague questions i have been posting. Would not do that again and get it right next time .

Comment: Sometimes you can, but then you already should know how to do the IR part, not start with the clustering. Most of the time in IR, clustering is done for result *presentation*, actually.